# How to cancel PrintPreviewControl print when exception occurs after selecting locked file

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, system.drawing

This is about printing to file like print to pdf and the like.

My problem is that when user selects locked file through SaveFileDialog-like window PrintDocument.Print() throws Win32Exception. I catch it and present error dialog to the user. User accepts it and..... application hangs despite swallowing exception.

Is there a workaround for this issue?

Note: i dont mind using unsafe or reflection if thats what it takes to handle this specific scenario. Also I use legacy WinForms on .NET Framework 4.8 if that affects available solutions.

Tried putting Print() in BackgroundWorker so that i can kill it in catch clause but doesnt work since that access UI object in separate from UI thread. Tried making custom PrintController but achieving quality parity with previous code turned out to be very problematic.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: relevant code

```cs
private void buttonPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath));
                if (askAsPrinterBodelBeforPrint)
                {
                    printDialog1.AllowCurrentPage = true;
                    printDialog1.AllowPrintToFile = false;
                    printDialog1.AllowSelection = true;
                    printDialog1.AllowSomePages = true;
                    printDialog1.PrinterSettings = document.PrinterSettings;
                    if (printDialog1.ShowDialog(this) != DialogResult.OK) return;
                }
                if ((this.printPreviewControl1.Document.PrinterSettings.PrintRange == PrintRange.CurrentPage)
                    || (this.printPreviewControl1.Document.PrinterSettings.PrintRange == PrintRange.Selection))
                {
                    this.printPreviewControl1.Document.PrinterSettings.PrintRange = PrintRange.SomePages;
                    this.printPreviewControl1.Document.PrinterSettings.FromPage = this.printPreviewControl1.StartPage + 1;
                    this.printPreviewControl1.Document.PrinterSettings.ToPage = this.printPreviewControl1.StartPage + 1;
                }

                this.printPreviewControl1.Document.Print(); //<- Open File Explorer. When user choose locked file then accept, exception is thrown. Normally after accept, print would begin and that works as expected IF not printing into locked file
                if (!frmPrintOptions.ClosePreview)
                    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Logger.LogError("frmPrintPrewiew:buttonPrint_Click:" + ee.Message);
                Logger.LogError("frmPrintPrewiew:buttonPrint_Click:" + ee.StackTrace);
                Logger.LogInfo("̣ie߫a robocza: " + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                MyKryptonMessageBox.Show(lang.ReadString(this.Name, "PrintError", "PrintError"));//<- at this point user can still interact with application by clicking popup with error. Only after accepting it application hangs
            }
        }
```

Comment: @LarsTech Done, thought there isnt much to go by when it comes to relevant code. Added few comments to code to clarify where problem occurs.

Comment: @HansPassant actually found issue finally and can't believe how simple it turned out. All i had to do was to add `DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel` to catch clause and finally application got unstuck.